# How can I make a string default to null instead of ""

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

In knockoutjs, you can bind a string to an input tag. If you do not tamper with this input the string remains `null` but if you type something and then clear it it goes to an empty string. How can I override this behaviour globally without modifing every binding.

Cheers.

Sam

Answer (score 3):

You can create a "new" observable function that wraps a computed responsible of converting empty strings to null. Then use it whenever you want to force null values:

### JS:

```
var forceNullObservable = function() {
    var obs = ko.observable();

    return ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return obs();
        },
        write: function(val) {
            if(val === '') {
                val = null;
            }
            obs(val);
        }
    });
};

// use forceNullObservable instead of ko.observable
vm = {
    val: forceNullObservable()
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

### Html:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: val"/>
```

#

#### [Demo: `JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/p55rtmr8/3/)

---

## Edit:

---

Modifying `forceNullObservable` to accept an external observable will achieve what you want without modifiying js code:

### JS:

```
window.forceNullObservable = function(obs) {

    return ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return obs();
        },
        write: function(val) {
            if(val === '') {
                val = null;
            }
            obs(val);
        }
    });
};

vm = {
    val: ko.observable()
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

### Html:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: forceNullObservable(val)"/>
```

#

#### [Demo: `JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/p55rtmr8/5/)

Comment: Hey. This would work (since I'm using the mapping plugin I could put this in the options) but it would force me to almost define my model. Event worst if my extenders that would have to be rewritten to account for this

Comment: Answer updated. Another solution that needs only html code modification.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it globally, but you should be able to use a custom value binding like this:

JS

```
ko.bindingHandlers.nonBlankValue = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // Subscribe to changes to the observable bound to the value binding:
        allBindingsAccessor().value.subscribe(function(newValue) {
            if (newValue === "") { this.target(null); }
        });
        // Initialise the standard underlying KO value binding:
        ko.bindingHandlers.value
            .init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
    update: ko.bindingHandlers.value.update
};
```

Markup

```
<input type="text" data-bind="nonBlankValue: modelProperty" />
```

Comment: This is one option, but I'm really looking for a way to maybe intercept the "value" bindingHandler

Comment: As far as I've found, you'd have to update the KO source code to do that.